# Android communication between activity and fragment

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-viewpager

I have an `activity` which contains a `ViewPager` inside it.The ViewPager's `Adapter` is `FragmentStatePagerAdapter`. Each page is `Fragment`.The `Fragment` contains a number of Threads. My problem is, I have to stop all the threads inside the fragment when `ViewPager's` page is changed.How can I do this ?

Comment: In short when fragment is not visible to user that fragment should stop all threads.right?

Comment: Each fragment have to set many imageview's image using setImageBitmap. It may lead to outofmemory exception.So I have to stop the threads if the page is changed.

Answer (score 9):

you have asked about communication between activity and fragment that you achieve using  interface:

**Your Fragment:**

```
public class YourFragment
    extends Fragment{

private OnListener listener;

 public interface OnListener
    {
        void onChange();
    }

void initialize( OnListener listener)
{

        this.listener = listener;
}


//onview pager change call your interface method that will go to the activity as it has the listener for interface. 

listener.onChange();
}
```

**Your Activity:**

```
public class yourActivity
    extends Activity
    implements yourFragment.OnListener
{

// intialize the method of fragment to set listener for interface where you define fragment.
yourFragment.initialize( this );

// implement what you want to do in interface method.

@Override
    public void onChange()
    {
     // implement what you want to do 
     }
}
```

hope it will help.

Comment: My ViewPager is inside the activity. So i have to implement the function inside the fragment.

Comment: This answer should be marked as answer, is one of the best I found.

Answer (score 1):

Android's philosophy with applications is to kill processes, so maybe following the same idea you could kill your Threads. Be aware though that this can lead to deadlocks if your Threads own locks, or monitors.


A more serious approach to me seems to use Thread.interrupt() from your Activity. Then your Threads in your Fragment have to check Thread.interrupted for interruption, and finish gracefully if they've been interrupted.

You can use Thread.join() if you want some synchronous behavior

In addition, you can wait for a certain amount of time for your Thread to finish gracefully using a Timer, then kill them on timeout.

Please have a look at [java.lang.Thread](http://developer.android.com/reference/java/lang/Thread.html)



To let this be more easy to implement, you could use a [ThreadPoolExecutor](http://developer.android.com/reference/java/util/concurrent/ThreadPoolExecutor.html) or some other helper of java.util.concurrent package.